# Can I enter the U.S. if I have a tourist visa B2 Validity of less than 6 months?

Tags: visas, b1-b2-visas

I have a tourist visa B2 and I am planning to visit the US in march 2018, my passport is valid for 10 years but my visa will expire on July 2018. I would like to know if there are any limitations of entering the US with a visa validity of less than 6 months.
thanks!

Comment: You can visit the US for up to 90 days with this visa as long as you leave the country before it expires.

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk No, US visas only need to be valid on the day of entry. The permission to stay you get when you enter is *independent* of the visa expiry.

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk in addition, the duration of stay for B visa travelers is six months, not 90 days.